# SSIS Script Task fails when run from sql job

Tags: ssis

I have a created a SSIS package to load excel file into database but before Data Flow Task, i m using a script task to change data type of one the excel columns using interop.excel dll.

While running the package in VS2015 on the server itself, it completes with success, but when i am running it through sql server agent it is getting failed and giving following error message

> "Script Task Error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation."

i have already registered the dll in GAC.

What others steps should i try to resolve the issue?

Edit :-

Error Message :

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: Did you register a 32 or 64 bit DLL? How are you running your SSIS package - the default of 64 bit mode or 32 bit mode?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have to register interop.excel.dll to the GAC unless you're trying to put the Office bits onto the machine without going through a proper installation. If so, that is probably a bad idea for a pair of reasons: licensing - you're putting your company at legal risk from a MS audit and security - that server won't be notified of patches to Office given the atypical install

Comment: Could be permissions.  Whatever the account running agent doesn't have permissions to the file used in the script task, maybe.   I would suggest adding a try catch to your script task to get a more meaningful error.   The accepted answer here shows how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651367/ssis-package-gives-error-after-deployment-sql-server-2012/52653538#52653538

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks for the link, i am able to get the error message, Below is the error message i am getting, 

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: did you research that error? Here's a couple I found with quick search you could explore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785063/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-error-80070005-access-is-de or this one is word but I'm sure would be similar for excel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the

Comment: Yes i did and apply some changes, now error has changed to 

"exception from hresult 0x800a03ec "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. As you succeed in running the package under your account and it fails run by SQL Job - the most probable case is that SQL Server Agent service account does not have an access to the Excel file.

I would create a job proxy, as described here [How to add SQL Job Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713464) with an account which has access to the Excel file.